# Count on third level associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following association:

Reservation 
- has_many reservation_occupations
ReservationOccupations
- has_many reservation_occupants
ReservationOccupants

I want to do the following queries:

1 - Get the number of occupants for one reservation
2 - Get the number of occupants for a group of reservations (Reservations.all for example)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 - Get the number of occupants for one reservation

First, add a `has_many :through` association from Reservation to ReservationOccupant:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservation_occupations
  has_many :reservation_occupants, through: :reservation_occupations
end
```

Now you can simply do

```
reservation = Reservation.first
reservation.reservation_occupants.count
```

> 2 - Get the number of occupants for a group of reservations

First, add some more associations:

```
class ReservationOccupant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reservation_occupation
  has_one :reservation, through: :reservation_occupation
end
```

and

```
class ReservationOccupation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reservation
  # ...
end
```

Then, to count the number of occupants for a group of reservations, you can add to your `Reservation` class the following method:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def self.num_occupants(reservations)
    ReservationOccupant
      .joins(:reservation_occupation)
      .joins(:reservation)
      .where("reservations.id": reservations)
      .count
  end
end
```

It's worth noting that this `num_occupants` method works regardless of whether `reservations` is a collection of reservations or a single reservation. In other words, this method could be used for both of your questions, #1 and #2. However, the first method generates a more efficient SQL query, and is arguably a little clearer, so I'd personally use that when finding the number of occupants for a single reservation.

Comment: That's awesome and sounds about right! Thanks for taking the time to explain everything :)